# How does browsers render iframe with different encoding of parent page?

Tags: html, iframe

I have a web page which is encoded in UTF-8, now I need to include a subpage by iframe which is encoded in GBK.

So I wonder how browsers(IE/Chrome/FF) render the characters of the whole page ? Will browsers treat the iframe page as a standalone page and use its own encoding charset ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why not test it and see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the browser will treat the iframe page as a standalone page as if it was being rendered in a separate tab or window.

There is, however, an issue with [some versions of Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192434/ie-loses-automatic-utf-8-encoding-in-iframe-form-target) where the content of the iframe does not set the encoding through the Content-Type, and picks up the parent window's encoding on its initial load.